# Add/Modify className Dynamically onMouseEnter

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to add a new **className** when the user **hovers** on a slick slider Image and perform some ***CSS*** transition for that particular Image card in the slider. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-slick-slider-issues how do I add **className** to the slider whenever the user hovers on the image or change the parent className based on the hover position?

I tried the **document.getElementsByClassName('unique-image')** but all the images have this className as they are looped inside a **map** function. how can I only change ***unique-image*** className if the user hovers on a certain image to ***unique-image-hover***?

Comment: Consider slightly updated version of my answer (since, there's nothing returned , `icon` variable is not getting defined). Other than that, it looks like your images are getting assigned arbitrary `className`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may access [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) that triggered `mouseEnter` and use [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) `add()` method to add your desired `className`

So, your `mouseEnter` handler may look like that:

```
const mouseHover = e =>{
  e.target.classList.add('someClassNameYouWantedToAdd')
}
```

Comment: When you using react, it's not a good practice to change the DOM directly

Comment: how can I use this to just rename the className from unique-image class1 to unique-image class2?

Comment: @ShermaysterPavel : In your solution it seems to me that doing state updates upon each `mouseEnter`/`mouseExit` (which will cause consequent re-renders) is a waste of performance. What exactly troubling you in my solution?

Comment: @visizky : there's no such thing as *renaming `className`*, you `remove()` one class and `add()` another, or `toggle()` those, respectively

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov :   var wTile =e.target.parentNode;
                                      wTile.className = wTile.className + " yeah";
is modifying the parent className

Comment: @visizky : that approach may become tricky to implement when you have multiple `className`'s applied, so I would rather do `classList.toggle()` which will switch on/off one class and do the opposite with another.

Comment: ok, suppose if the image is deeply nested and I want to toggle the className which is at the very top, how can I achieve this?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov when you are adding or removing class, you want to rerender. React sync DOM with your data. If your change DOM directly, it can break syncing

Comment: @visizky : above solution doesn't depend on how deeply your component is nested within components tree

Comment: @ShermaysterPavel : I may accept that comment for the cases you modify actual DOM contents. However, simple animation (which is the case here) doesn't seem to be worth those re-renders.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov the problem that you directly changing DOM created by React. It can introduce unexpected behavior and bugs in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I can use React.useState

```js
const [hoveredClass, setHoveredClass] = React.useState("");

 const updateHovered = (e) => {
   setHoveredClass(e.target.id)   
 }

const removeHovered = (e) => {
   setHoveredClass('')
}

return (
  <div className={`someStaticClass ${hoveredClass ? "hoveredClass" : ""}`}
   onMouseEnter={updateHovered}
   onMouseExit={removeHovered}
  >
   {list. map(item => (
      <ImageChildComponent {...item} />  
    )}

 </div>
 )
```

Target will give you a child element, but you can add an event listener to the parent.

As @YevgenGorbunkov mention, change in state will trigger rerendering, so
consider wrapping ImageChildComponent with [React memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) to prevent unnecessary rendering

Comment: The child is deeply nested and we have to change the className of the parent if the user hovers in the child Image, you have any other alternatives?

Comment: you can use React Context for nested elements https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: But if can provide more details about your problem, maybe I will suggest a better solution

Comment: I have a div with className parent and subsequent children with classNames class1 to class4 and inside class4, I have the slider and based on the mouseHover want to change the parent div with className parent to parent hover